# Replacing a fixed value in a limit with an expression?

Tags: calculus, limits

At 2:25 of the video youtube.com/watch?v=3ol-3uZfC-E , the () used in the top question "Why isn't ()=|| differentiable at =0?" is a function. But then if we look at the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$, this () being used means a fixed value because it represents a coordinate of an arbitrary point that will get infinitely close to $(0,f(0))$. So now () takes on two different meanings. It's both a function and a coordinate at the same time. And then the guy, without any explanation why, ends up plugging in || at 2:25 which means he's plugging in a function for a fixed value which makes no sense. However, his final answer is correct so how is he able to do this?

Comment: $f$ is a function. The expression $f(x)$ is the value of $f$ for the input $x$. So replacing $f(x)$ by $|x|$ is fine, in this context. On the whole, the video does a pretty good job.

Comment: When $()=||$ is used in "Why isn't ()=|| differentiable at =0?" he's clearly implying $()=||$ is a function though.

Comment: $f(x)=|x|$ is the _definition_ of the function $f$. It declares that for a given input $x$, the function $f$ gives the output $|x|$.

Comment: The phrase "the function $f(x)=|x|$" is just an informal shortened version of "the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$".

Comment: Still in the limit, after replacing $f(x)$ with ||,  || is not a fixed value because x can be any value. On the other hand, $f(0)$ is a fixed value. So how can we subtract a fixed value from a value that isn't fixed?

Comment: Before taking the limit, $|x|$ is regarded as fixed, but unknown, so subtracting $0$ from $|x|$ is perfectly OK at that stage. Also note that for any positive $x$ value, $\frac{|x|}{x}=1$, and for any fixed negative $x$ value, $\frac{|x|}{x}=-1$.

Comment: So since ()=|| is the definition of the function $f$, this means for a given (so any) input , the function  gives the output ||. So || is clearly not fixed at this point because you said for "a given input". BUT, when we plug in || into the limit, we now regard || as fixed. Is this what you are saying? Excuse me if I am asking a question you already answered I can't see all the updates when I'm typing.

Comment: Before taking the limit, we regard $x$ as fixed (and nonzero).

Comment: So in the question "Why isn't ()=|| differentiable at =0?", || is fixed?

Comment: It's fixed when simplifying $|x|-0$.

Comment: Would you agree that for all values of $x$, we have $x+x=2x$? In order for it to work, we assume $x$ is _fixed_ for the duration of the simplification.

Comment: Is that in the video or separate?

Comment: Yes I would agree.

Comment: Similarly, for any value of $x$, we have $|x|-0=|x|$.

Comment: Wait when you say "in order for it work, we assume  is fixed for the duration of the simplification", you are saying that we can't add two numbers that are changing constantly. Those two numbers have to be fixed then addition makes sense.

Comment: Yes, exactly.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Then I do understand now that the two ||'s in $||−0=||$ are fixed. So in the question "Why isn't ()=|| differentiable at =0?", || isn't fixed. But when we plug in ||, it has to be fixed in order for addition to make sense.

Comment: As I already explained, the simplifications take place _before_ taking the limit, so in that context, $x$ is fixed, but unknown.

Comment: So every || in the video is fixed but unknown.

Comment: When you say $|x|$ isn't fixed, you are misinterpreting the context. Although the value of $x$ is arbitrary, when using it in an algebraic expression, it's regarded as fixed but unknown.

Comment: So $x$ is always fixed right, its not just fixed in certain circumstances? When I say not fixed, that actually makes no sense because it implies $x$ is constantly changing. For example, to even evaluate ()=||, $x$ has to be fixed because you need to pin down your input so you get a fixed output.

Comment: I think I was confusing "unknown" with "not fixed" when "not fixed" makes no sense.

Comment: When actually taking the limit, we force $x$ to vary. But the expression inside the limit assumes a fixed $x$, hence, at the stage before taking the limit, since $x$ is regarded as fixed, we can apply any legal algebraic simplification.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now, when taking the limit, x is never fixed because it is infinitely getting closer to  zero in the video. But, aside from the one exception of taking a limit, x is ALWAYS fixed right? That's why we can plug in || at 2:25.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your studies!